# Selecionar primeiras linhas dependendo do grupo eficientemente

Tags: r, data.frame, dplyr

Suponha que eu tenho a seguinte base de dados

```
set.seed(100)
base <- expand.grid(grupo = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), score = runif(100))
```

E que eu queira selecionar as linhas com menor `score` dependendo do grupo de acordo com a tabela abaixo:

```
qtds <- data.frame(grupo = levels(base$grupo), qtd = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
qtds

  grupo qtd
1     a   1
2     b   2
3     c   3
4     d   4
```

Isto é, desejo selecionar a linha com menor `score`do  grupo `a`, as duas linhas com menor `score` do grupo `b` e assim por diante...

No momento, estou fazendo assim:

```
novaBase <- data.frame()
for(i in levels(base$grupo)){
  novaBase <- rbind(novaBase,
                    base %>% 
                      filter(grupo == i) %>% 
                      filter(row_number(score) <= qtds$qtd[qtds$grupo == i])
                    )
}

   grupo        score
1      a 0.0003950703
2      b 0.0003950703
3      b 0.0039051792
4      c 0.0003950703
5      c 0.0221628349
6      c 0.0039051792
7      d 0.0269371939
8      d 0.0003950703
9      d 0.0221628349
10     d 0.0039051792
```

Deste jeito funciona, mas me parece muito ineficiente, além do código ser difícil de compreender. Alguém sabe um jeito melhor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma com o `dplyr` seria:

```
base2 <- merge(base, qtds)

base2 %>% group_by(grupo) %>% arrange(score) %>% slice(1:unique(qtd))
Source: local data frame [10 x 3]
Groups: grupo

   grupo      score qtd
1      a 0.03014575   1
2      b 0.03014575   2
3      b 0.03780258   2
4      c 0.03014575   3
5      c 0.03780258   3
6      c 0.05638315   3
7      d 0.03014575   4
8      d 0.03780258   4
9      d 0.05638315   4
10     d 0.09151028   4
```

Comment: Legal!! Não tinha pensado nisso!